# Upside down text for report?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-office

For specific reasons, I need to be able to display some values on the bottom half of my report upside down(inverted). The intention of this report is to be printed and folded down the middle, so I would like for it to adhere to this specific format. I can't find anything that does this easily. Some ideas that I have considered but don't know how to implement:

**'importing' an upside-down font and setting the control's font to that font?**

**somehow inverting the entire control 180 degrees**

Does anyone have any experience accomplishing this?

**Edit: installing an upside down font and setting the control source's font property to that font was the solution that I implemented. For some upside down fonts, it may be necessary to call str_reverse on the text, as the upside down font may reverse the order  Problem is-- This would only work on the computer with the font installed, right?**

Comment: Yes, this will only work on computers that have the font installed. You will need to distribute the font with your application (check the license!).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your options are:

- Lebans: http://www.lebans.com/
- Word mail merge
- An upside down font
- An image.

Access has a Vertical property, but that is only for 90°.

Comment: I noticed that you added 'an image.' The problem with this solution is that the control that I want to flip is based on a value of a control (it's dynamic). So I don't think that would work. I'm working on using a downloaded upside-down font as a solution. I'll update shortly to let you know how it works.

Comment: An image is just there for completeness.

Comment: If you can only rotate 90° but not 180°, you could of course rotate both sides. For example left side -90° rotation, right side 90° rotation.

Comment: @Deruijter It is not 90°, it is `Vertical = Yes` and I do not think there is anything you can use to contain a textbox except a supreport and that does not have the property, AFAIK.

Comment: My solution was to download an upside down font and install it to my windows. After restarting access, I set the control source's font to this upside down font. This particular upside down font reversed my text also. I can call str_reverse on this control to fix this and it will be working. Thanks for your suggestions.