# Rotate Labels in Access Reports

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I'm stuck on being unable to rotate the text in an access report. I currently have an excel spreadsheet that I'm basing the Access Report off of. The Report has to look as near to the exact same as the Excel Spreadsheet as I can make it.

I've looked all around and haven't been able to find any solutions that work or even look halfway decent.

All I need to do is rotate about 15 labels 90deg counter clockwise. What kind of solutions can I use to achieve this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11505622/upside-down-text-for-report

Comment: I tried running that, but it doesn't work in 2013.

Comment: Running what? Lebans? Why not just use Excel http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/vertical-labels-t1884337.html&p=1884341#entry1884341 ?

Comment: Well I haven't been able to figure out how to read the query and properly display the data in excel. Also, I've already got the entire form designed in Access aside from a few rotated headers.

Comment: In that case, why not just accept the limitations of the Vertical property -- Property sheet >> Other ?

Comment: I'm replicating a form set by an outside organization. That is a possibility, but I am currently not sure of how much of an issue that would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way I found around this was to simply use photoshop to create the header labels and rotate them into the necessary positions I needed.

Answer (score 0):

There is a "Vertical" property for labels, see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195518.aspx). However, it does only clockwise rotation. I'd wish to find a solution to make a counter-clockwise rotation too.